# How to install pyrealsense2 on Mac Os?

Tags: python, macos, installation, realsense

After **several attempts** of installation, through pip or even source code, I had lots of errors with cmake, missing files, module not found etc.
I tried with several different versions of python and pip and the **most common error** was `ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrealsense2`. I even tried to install with `brew` but without success.
Has anyone managed to install this module on Mac OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only way** I could install it was with the following command:

```
pip install pyrealsense2 -f https://github.com/cansik/pyrealsense2-macosx/releases
```

It may work with other python versions, but the one I used was 3.8.8.

Thanks to **@cansik** for helping me with your github post, available at:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/9687

Comment: `pip install pyrealsense2` was enough for me